# Insert one row at any index in TableView with custom Cell

Tags: ios, tableview

I'm newbie on iOS. I tried more time to search but the result is not my wish. The first, I have 5 rows with the custom cell. Cell contains only text and I want to add one row at any index with cell that contains one image. So how we can implement it ?

Comment: For displaying text label and a single image no need to use custom cells. You can use the default cell. Your question is  not clear. What you want actually. Insert a cell or use different type cells in a table view

Comment: Actually, I use custom cell that contain text and after I want to add anything in this custom cell. For inserting new row I need only image in cell but I don't know I must use the same cell or different.

Comment: By default a UITableViewCell is associated with an image view, text label and detail text label. If your cell is nothing looks like this you can go with the custom cell so you can customize it for your needs. Use different custom cells when cells looks differently. All those things depends your need. First you have to try something. Then some problem arises ask here with your code

Comment: @Anil if I want add row at index 1, how do we do ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the comments i came to know you are very new to UITableView. So please go through some of the given tutorial. You will be able to add, remove edit cells in UITableView

[UITableView tutorial](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/10/uitableview-tutorial/)
[tutorial 2](http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.in/2012/10/adding-uitableview-tutorial.html)
[Table view programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html)

For simple insertion do like this

Add button and its action to the view

```
 -(IBAction)addNewRow:(UIButton *)sender
 {
  self.numberOfRows++;  // update the data source    
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
   [self.tableview insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

 }
```

**Edit**

I think you need some thing like this

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *cellID1=@"CellOne";
NSString *cellID2=@"CellTwo";

UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

if (0 == indexPath.row) {

    cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID1];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID1];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"New Cell";

}

else
{
    cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID2];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID2];
    }
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Test.jpg"];
}

return cell;
}
```

Dont forget increment the cell count ie now return 6 from numberOfRows.

Comment: If we want to add this row directly in TableView, what should we do?

Comment: I don't use button action to add the row. I have already 5 rows but I want to add one more.

Answer (score 1):

you can insert rows into table from anywhere in the view controller

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

give the proper `indexPaths` and row animation.

Comment: write it in method didSelectRowAtIndexPath or cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: when do you want to add a row? when you touch some button?

Comment: for example if you press a button then row should be added, in this case we should write this in that button action. here tableView is the tableView name that you gave in your code.

Comment: I don't use button action to add the row. I have already 5 rows but I want to add one more.

Comment: then increase the numberofRows and give proper data in cellForRowAtIndexpath.

Comment: if you want to add dynamically you can add like above post or else just increase the numberofrows.

Answer (score 0):

In your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, differentiate between the index path where you want the cell with the image and add it there, otherwise only set the text of the UITableViewCell.