# How to add view beside tableviewcell with Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I'd like to add view beside tableviewcell when user click table view cell.

before user click

---cell1---
---cell2---

after user clicked

---cell1---
---detailview---
---cell2---
How to do that?

Comment: To insert views between cells, you'll need a table view section header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for something like another view appearing below the tapped cell and not an expanding tapped cell,you can *insert a tableview cell* just after the tapped cell.Use **insertRowsAtIndexPaths** and insert the cell.You can create this cell as a custom cell.

Comment: here its explained well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16183134/insert-one-row-at-any-index-in-tableview-with-custom-cell

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 options to do that:
 - To make detailView as another cell, just insert below the cell user clicks
 - Cell add the detailView initially. And make a switch to show it or hide it.Just because cell in table view is reused, we should not add subview in a cell already in table view, which will cause some problem in reusing.